# Sql Query to Generate Matrix data from single table in SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have single table to have records for GUESTS. I want to make a matrix each guest connected with each other within group. Please see image for better data understanding.

i.e. below Input record

```
RecKeyID    GuestID Check In-date   Check Out-date  Room NO
1           1001    1/1/2020            1/2/2020    7
1           1002    1/1/2020            1/2/2020    7
1           1003    1/1/2020            1/2/2020    7
1           1004    1/1/2020            1/2/2020    7
2           9997    1/1/2020            1/2/2020    9
2           9998    1/1/2020            1/2/2020    9
2           9999    1/1/2020            1/2/2020    9
```

Query Output

```
RecKeyID    GuestID Contact Guest   Check In-date   Check Out-date  Room NO
1               1001    1002            1/1/2020        1/2/2020    7
1               1001    1003            1/1/2020        1/2/2020    7
1               1001    1004            1/1/2020        1/2/2020    7
1               1002    1001            1/1/2020        1/2/2020    7
1               1002    1003            1/1/2020        1/2/2020    7
1               1002    1004            1/1/2020        1/2/2020    7
1               1003    1001            1/1/2020        1/2/2020    7
1               1003    1002            1/1/2020        1/2/2020    7
1               1003    1004            1/1/2020        1/2/2020    7
1               1004    1001            1/1/2020        1/2/2020    7
1               1004    1002            1/1/2020        1/2/2020    7
1               1004    1003            1/1/2020        1/2/2020    7
2               9997    9998            1/1/2020        1/2/2020    9
2               9997    9999            1/1/2020        1/2/2020    9
```

so on

Input Table name : Trace
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9p92h.png)

Query Output from the above data :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BI7t5.png)

Comment: Mysql and spl-server are not the same. Pleasde tag correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the `sql-server` code, correct the column names (if any are miss spelled)

```
SELECT t1.RecKeyId
    ,t1.GuestId
    ,t2.GuestId [Contact Guest]
    ,t1.CheckInDate
    ,t1.CheckOutDate
    ,t1.RoomNo
FROM Trace t1
JOIN Trace t2 ON t1.RoomNo = t2.RoomNo
    AND t1.GuestId != t2.GuestId
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was trying long logic..omg.. silly mistake...